# Is "often too hard" a verb phrase?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> People work hard, often too hard for money

Is this sentence correct?

Is "often too hard" a verb phrase?

Comment: People work hard, often (they work) too hard for money.

Comment: Correct? I don't think so. I think people are lazy and don't work hard enough for their wages. Or perhaps you're asking if it's _grammatically_ correct? (Btw, I think it's an [adverbial phrase](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm).)

Answer (score 1):

You sentence is correct, but *often too hard* is not a verb phrase.

**Verb phrases**  comprise the verb, plus the complement, object, or adverb. Verb phrases, such as "She was walking quickly to the mall" comprise the verb (walking) and the complement (to the mall).

Comment: Is it an adverbial phrase as suggested by JR ?

Comment: Yes:  Adverbial Phrases
Adverbial phrase (or adverb phrase) is the term for two or more words which play the role of an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

As written, OP sentence is *not* correct, because ***often too hard*** is a [parenthetical phrase](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/parenthetical-phrases/) which should be delimited by commas or dashes, or enclosed in brackets...

> *People work hard**,** often too hard**,** for money*
>    *People work hard — often too hard — for money*
>    *People work hard (often too hard) for money*

In OP's specific context, the parenthetical "afterthought/clarification" simply modifies the preceding ***hard***.